# How do you prove that the "c" guaranteed by the Mean Value Theorem for a quadractic function is the midpoint of the interval [a,b]?

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a quadratic function. Prove the Mean Value Theorem applies to $f$ on any closed interval $[a,b]$ and that the "$c$" guaranteed by the Mean Value Theorem is the midpoint of the interval.

How do I go about solving this? I understand how the Mean Value Theorem works but I don't know how it can prove that the c is the midpoint of the interval. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: First calculate $f((b)-f(a))/(b-a)$, for any quadratic you should get a fairly nice formula. Next, examine the derivative, which will be linearly. Set it equal to $f((b)-f(a))/(b-a)$. this gives a linear equation with one indeterminate.

Comment: It should be quite mechanical. Take an arbitrary quadratic $f(x) = px^2 + qx + r$, and solve $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$ for $c$. Hopefully the one and only solution is $c = \frac{a + b}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that this specifically says "quadratic function".  This isn't true for just any function, f.  Write $f(x)= px^2+ qx+ r$.  The rest of this is just computation.  At x= a that is $pa^2+ qa+ r$.  At x= b it is $pb^2+ qb+ r$.  $\frac{f(b)- f(a)}{b- a}= \frac{pb^2- qb+ r- pa^2- qa+ r}{b- a}= \frac{p(b^2- a^2)+ q(b- a)}{b- a}= \frac{p(b+a)(b-a)+ q(b-a)}{b-a}= p(b+a)+ q$.

On the other hand $f'= 2px+ q$.  The "mean value theorem" says that there exit a point, c, such that $f'(c)= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b- a}$.  Here that means that $2pc+ q= p(b+a)+ q$.  From that $2pc= p(b+a)$ so that $c= \frac{b+a}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply MVT, we know that $f$ must be continuous on the closed interval $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$. Then MVT guarantees that there exists
$$f ^ { \prime } ( c ) = \frac { f ( b ) - f ( a ) } { b - a }$$
You want to show that $c = \frac{a+b}{2}$ as this is the midpoint between $a, b$.

We can verify this through algebraic simplification and substitution. Let $f(x) = px^2+qx+z$. Then $f'(x) = 2px + q$ such that $a \neq 0$.

Plug in $a, b$ in for $x$ in $f(x) = px^2+qx+z$ and then plug that expression into $\frac { f ( b ) - f ( a ) } { b - a }$.

You should then get 
$p(b+a) + q$

Then plug $c$ in for $x$ in $f'(x)$ and you should get $pc + q$. Note that these two values are equivalent according to MVT. Or if you substitute $\frac{a+b}{c}$ for $c$ in $f'(x)$ then you will see that the expressions are equivalent.