# How do you prove that the c in MVT is NOT the midpoint of the interval [a, b]?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question is:

[image: Let f(x) = Mx^3 + Nx^2 + Px + Q, where M is not equal to 0. Prove that for any interval [a, b], the number c guarenteed by MVT is not equal to the midpoint (a+b)/2 of the interval]

I'm not sure how to answer this but I saw this post with a smimilar question: [How do you prove that the "c" guaranteed by the Mean Value Theorem for a quadractic function is the midpoint of the interval [a,b]?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978458/how-do-you-prove-that-the-c-guaranteed-by-the-mean-value-theorem-for-a-quadrac)

I would just like to ask if the procedure for answering the question is the same? Or is there an additional step or explanation? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to show that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ (with $b\ne a)$ is never the same as $f'(\frac{a+b}2)$. Start by writing down and simplifying both expressions. You *may* be able to use the positive result for quadratics to simplify the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, the basic idea is to show that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \ne f'(\frac{a+b}{2})$ regardless of your choice of $M$, $N$, $P$, and $Q$. Thus, we simply must evaluate both, and then demonstrate that they are not equal.
First, $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{Mb^3+Nb^2+Pb+Q-Ma^3-Na^2-Pa-Q}{b-a}=\frac{M(b^3-a^3)+N(b^2-a^2)+P(b-a)}{b-a}$$
This, by difference of squares and difference of cubes, is $$\frac{M(b-a)(b^2+ba+a^2)+N(b-a)(b+a)+P(b-a)}{b-a}=M(a^2+ab+b^2)+N(a+b)+P$$
Next, we must compute $f'\big(\frac{a+b}{2}\big)$, with
$f'(x)=3Mx^2+2Nx+P$ quite trivially, so
$$f'\Big(\frac{a+b}{2}\Big)=3M\Big(\frac{a+b}{2}\Big)^2+2N\Big(\frac{a+b}{2}\Big)+P$$
$$=\frac{3M}{4}(a^2+2ab+b^2)+N(a+b)+P$$
Next, to set up a proof by contradiction, we assume  these two values equal are to each other, so that $$M(a^2+ab+b^2)+N(a+b)+P=\frac{3M}{4}(a^2+2ab+b^2)+N(a+b)+P$$
$$M(a^2+ab+b^2)=\frac{3M}{4}(a^2+2ab+b^2)$$
$$M(a^2+ab+b^2)=\frac{3M}{4}(a^2+ab+b^2)+\frac{3M}{4}(ab)$$
$$\frac{M}{4}(a^2+ab+b^2)=\frac{3M}{4}(ab)$$
Because $M$ is non zero, we can now do $$a^2+ab+b^2=3ab$$
$$a^2-2ab+b^2=0$$
This, of course, factors to $(a-b)^2=0$, which means that $a-b=0$, which means that $a=b$, which is not possible, because then $[a,b]$ wouldn't be an interval, it would be a point. Thus, our assumption must have been incorrect, which was that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = f'(\frac{a+b}{2})$, thus $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \ne f'(\frac{a+b}{2})$, proving the desired statement.